# Avoid exceptions at first start of application when SEQUENCE does't exist

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, payara

We are using sequences for ID generation. The sequences are stored in its own tables in the database.

```java
private static final String SEQ = "seq_gen_myentity";
    
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = SEQ, allocationSize = 50, initialValue = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SEQ)
private Long id;
```

When the application is started for the first time in development environment with empty database, the tables with sequences don't exist and I'm getting following exception **for each entity** in the server log:

```
[EL Warning]: 2021-03-05 09:23:20.345--ServerSession(1078388861)--Exception [EclipseLink-1002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.1): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: SEQUENCE 'APP.SEQ_GEN_MYENTITY' does not exist.
```

Is it possible to avoid exceptions for not existing sequences at the first start of the application with empty database?

Comment: These are just warning messages aren't they? Turn down the log level to avoid warnings

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have to agree that would be the best solution. Thank you very much!